# ningx, uwsgi, python permanent mysql error after some time from starting application

Tags: python, mysql, uwsgi

I'm using nginx as frontend server and uwsgi for python applications. About one time a day one of my applications starts falling. In log I can see different mysql errors. For example:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

or

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)") None None
```

Also there were something about `can't locate row column for column ...`. And maybe more interesting:

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

What help's - I'm killing my uwsgi process and run it again. Interesting thing is other apps (they also use mysql) are ok and continue to work.

If I just kill forks nothing happens. I must kill master process.

My uwsgi config is:

```
module = stulyev
callable = app
pp = /home/krasulya/apps/stulyev.net
logto = /var/log/stulyev.net.log
touch-reload = /tmp/stulyev.net.sock
socket = /tmp/stulyev.net.sock
uid = krasulya
gid = www-data
daemonize = /var/log/stulyev.net.daemon.log
reload-on-exception = true
harakiri = 30
max-requests = 10000
harakiri-verbose = 1
buffer-size = 65535
```

What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not open the database connection in the master. Not all sqlalchemy adapter supports it. Open the connection one time per worker or add lazy-apps = true to uWSGI to load the whole app at every fork: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a rational idea, I agree. How can I prevent master process from connecting to database? I thought master should not serve any requests and redirect all of them them to workers.

Comment: if you do not want to use lazy-apps, you can decorate your connection function with @postfork (after having imported uwsgidecorators) in this way it will be re-executed whenever uWSGI calls fork()

Comment: Do you mean that if I will use lazy-apps (I have nothing against on first glance) master process will not connect to database?

And can you please explain why I have this problem at all? Why problem occurs only in 8-24 hours from uwsgi server start?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @postfork is key here. If running a Flask app as I am it doesn't run well with --lazy-apps. For example form validation of csrf tokens fails across workers. Moving sqlAlchemy instance creation into a decorated function worked for me!